# Is there any reason to use Apache HashCodeBuilder over Objects.hash?

Tags: java, hashcode

I am overriding the hashCode and equals method of an object.  I am using [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) from the Apache Commons library for overriding equals.  Since I am using Java 7, I was planning to use the built-in [hash method in the Objects class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash%28java.lang.Object...%29) instead of the Apache Commons [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html).  Is there anything wrong with this approach? Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 4):

`HashCodeBuilder` has the funky reflective hash code implementation, but other than that, no -- you should probably use `Objects`.

Answer (score 4):

One difference is that `HashCodeBuilder` can compute the hash code reflectively:

```
public int hashCode() {
  return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
}
```

That is, using `HashCodeBuilder`, you don't have to list the individual fields, although you can.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but wanted to add the general rule regarding third-party libraries:

**Always use methods from the standard libraries over importing a third-party library.**

The main reasons to avoid third-party libraries are:

1. *you will probably only use a small percentage of the imported functionalities*
2. *external libraries can introduce security vectors that you are not aware of*
3. *you will need to keep dependencies up-to-date to ensure any (security and logic) fixes in the library will make it into your project*
4. *it creates bloat in your project and application*

There is only a single reason to use a third-party library:

*it contains functionality that is not available in the standard libraries and will be hard to create yourself*